# AWS Elastic Cache Redis with C#

Tags: c#, redis, amazon-elasticache

I couldn't find any good documentation to read redis cache items using AWS SDK.
AmazonElasticCacheClient class doesn't give any method to read the information. Which class should I use to insert and read cache entries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AWS SDK is only used to **manage** ElastiCache, not to use it. To connect to Redis instance and read/write information you'll have to use any of third-party libraries. Official Redis documentation provides a very good list of those: https://redis.io/clients#c